# Name a PNG file saved from Canvas using an "open with" dialog

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working with canvas and I would be able to save my Canvas to png.

By looking around, I discover the great toDataURL() function given by the W3C.

I am also already using the canvas2image from  nihilogic that we can found on this page : http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

I noticed that on canvas2image, the developpers use the "image/octet-stream" which open the "open with" dialog box but give some problem :

-picture name is the ascii returned by toDataUrl().

-file extension is .part when downloaded

In short, I would prompt the "open with" dialog box with something like "myImage.png" when clicking on a button.

Is it possible ? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : I have the contraint to use only Javascript, I can't use [some nice PHP trick](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you aim to only modern browsers and don't care cross-browser that much, there's a possible solution with "download" attribute of  element.
Here's one sample for your information:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" download="testXXX.jpg">DOWNLOAD ME!</a>
```

Only one line, no javascript, yeah! You can change the href part into data url, and that works too.

Check this [Eric's tutorial](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) on html5rocks for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately not. Currently `data` URIs (used by that canvas2image module; quite neat, actually) do not support specifying filename or content-disposition headers, so the only way to force the browser to generate a *save as* dialog is to set the content-type to octet-stream.

Comment: So, there is also no way to customize the name of the URIs when using something like that ? :

window.location = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

Comment: The issue is that if you change the content type to an image content type (such as *image/png*), the browser displays it, instead of prompting to save. Normally (if using a server side solution) you can set the **Content-Disposition** header to force a download and a filename, but the `data` URI doesn't support that (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AData%3A_URI_scheme#Disadvantages for more details).

Comment: Note: In HTML5 it is now possible to download an image with custom names using the `download` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the real world web applications Hangrui Gao's solution is far from acceptable, according to

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

you'll deny this feature to all IE, Safari, IOS Safari, Android's users.

I think that given this limit in Canvas2Image, a better solution is to use some server side logic as explained [here](http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/)

Linuxatico