# A cross-browser alternative to Canvas2Image or HTML5 download attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

While developing a [pattern generator](http://bit.ly/hexagrid) I am running into the same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045603/name-a-png-file-saved-from-canvas-using-an-open-with-dialog) question from 2011.

The answers given don't really offer a **cross-browser**, **client-side** solution.

I would accept any of the following solutions when clicking the **Export Pattern** button:

1. Triggering a download through canvas2image while ensuring that the file is saved with a .png extension (no matter what the filename is set to) **or**,
2. Display a widget (KendoUI preferably) with the image resulting from the `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG()` method and let the user save it from there preferably not using the lame right-click solution, but with a link or a button.

HTML for the button I'm currently using:

```
<button id="downloadbtn" onClick="javascript:downloadImage()" data-role="button" class="k-button">Export Pattern</button>
```

Function that triggers the download:

```
function downloadImage () {

    //...extra code omitted
    var oCanvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
    oCanvas.width = $("#pixels-h").val();
    oCanvas.height = $("#pixels-v").val(); 
    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
    //...extra code omitted    

  }
```

The file seems to download fine under OSX with Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 and Safari Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2).

I have a report of someone unable to open the file after downloading it under Firefox 17.0.1 for OSX. Apparently the download generates a .part file.

**The biggest issue is that without a file extension I doubt that this method can be reliable.**

I am looking for a client-side only solution with the widest possible compatibility with current browsers, so I guess the HTML5 `download` attribute would not do the trick as it is currently only supported in Chrome.

Any creative solutions?

Comment: As two years have passed I'd like to ping if there are any better solutions for current browsers that include iOS 8/ OSX?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.  The basic problem is the filename needs to be added in the header but canvas2images uses document.location.href = strData and strData doesnt have headers.  So the answer is, canvas2image does not support the feature we need, and we will need to try another solution.  (for example perhaps FileSaver.js and canvas-toBlob.js)

http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Thanks! FileSaver looks really promising, though looking at the supported browsers on Github it seems that no version of Safari supports filenames, does this mean that a PNG extension would not be possible on Safari?

Comment: I don't know if it would work on Safari, it wouldn't hurt to try and find out.

Comment: @EricHartford it doesn't. Neither on desktop or mobile, which is very unfortunate. I'm thinking of having FileSaver.js as primary solution and than back it up with an API, that will either change the HTTP Header to trigger the download or upload an image based on passed base64 string and then respond with it's url to the client-side.