# Storing Image into png file

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I want to store the webpage into png file using javascript.I tired with the below sample code. but what is the issue is when I am downloading it's downloading extension is `image/octet-stream` but during downloading the file  I want to store the image in png format.How can i download the image from image/octet-stream extenstion to png extension.
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>html2canvas example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script>

    <style>
    canvas{border:1px solid #222}
    </style>
</head>
<body id="target">
      <a class="upload"  >Upload to Imgur</a>  
    <a href="#" download="testXXX.jpg" onclick="printImg()" ><img src="images/print-icon.png" alt="Print" width="16" height="16" ></a>
    <h2>this is <b>bold</b> <span style="color:red">red</span></h2>   
    <p> Feedback form with screenshot This script allows you to create feedback forms which include a screenshot, 
    created on the clients browser, along with the form. 
    The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real 
    representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the 
    information available on the page. How does it work? The script is based on the html2canvas library,
     which renders the current page as a canvas image, by reading the DOM and the different styles applied 
     to the elements. This script adds the options for the user to draw elements on top of that image, 
     such as mark points of interest on the image along with the feedback they send.
      It does not require any rendering from the server, as the whole image is created on the clients browser.
       No plugins, no flash, no interaction needed from the server, just pure JavaScript! Browser compatibility Firefox 3.5+ Newer versions of Google Chrome, Safari & Opera IE9
    </p>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function printImg(){
        html2canvas( [ document.body ],{
          onrendered: function(canvas) {

          var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png","image/octet-stream;base64");                 
          window.location.href=img;

          }
        });
      }


    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is just how toDataURL works.

See the following question for an answer with a somewhat ugly solution:

[Name a PNG file saved from Canvas using an "open with" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045603/name-a-png-file-saved-from-canvas-using-an-open-with-dialog)

(the href in the answer would point to the 'img' var in your javascript)

Comment: I need to download it to my local system, the above link u shared says to download it in server

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the chosen answer creates a link which, when clicked, causes your browser to download the image. The main point though, is that it's not universally (for all browsers) possible to download a screenshot with only the Canvas toDataUrl function.

Comment: Hi  madeddie, Then is there any other client-side approach  where we can take the screenshot and store it in png file

Comment: Not really, why do you need it? Maybe there is another kind of solution we can think of.

Comment: What exactly I need it is,In my application I want to keep the print button, when user click on the print button, it need to take the screen capture of my application and store it in png file.

Comment: This is not a why, but a what :) Why does it have to be client-side? Could you not render the page through PHP or something and generate a png that way?

Comment: I dont know php, I can try with jsp ,html and javascript